# Tableau: Filter dimensions depending on the criteria selected by a parameter

Tags: dynamic, filter, parameters, tableau-api

A parameter is being used to change which dimensions are displayed in a table.

I need to be able to filter on these dimensions as they are selected, without having the filter remain when a new dimension is selected.
Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to source a solution elsewhere, posting here should anyone have the same problem:

You need to create a new field using an if statement that queries your parameter. Something like:

```
IF [Parameter] = 'Category' AND NOT([Category]='Unwanted')
THEN [Category]
ELSEIF [Parameter] = 'Country' AND NOT([Country]='Unknown')
THEN [Country]
...\\repeat for every dimension selectable in your parameter
END
```

In your table replace *Number of records* with a count of this new field and voila.